# Xen Remus setup

Tags: virtualization, xen, high-availability, remus

Currently, I'm running the IT for a small organization, and we just purchased a new server to replace our aging Dell poweredge.  As the Dell isn't so bad as to be junk, I was hoping to set up Xen on the new server, then convert the old to be a failover target through Xen Remus.  However, I have been completely unable to get the remus tool on our new server.  I've tried the following:

*CentOS 5.5, stock, and with compiling Xen from source for a custom 2.6.32 kernel (encountered an error we couldn't debug during boot when attempting to use custom kernel)
*Debian 6.0
*Ubuntu 10.04 (non-mainline Xen packages)

I've managed to get the dom0 running on all of them, but none of the versions that have run have had Remus.

Does anyone know of a tutorial that encompasses setting up Remus from the ground up, or know what OS I could use as a dom0 that would include remus with a xen package?  So far, I have not found any resources related to Remus that start prior to having the tool already installed.

Comment: What did you use instead of remus up until now?

Comment: Old question, but from the wiki (requirements) - "Xen hypervisor with remus support and tools (included with Xen 4.0+)
Note: Remus is not included with XCP, XenServer, or with some of the Linux pre-packaged versions of Xen, so please check your distribution or you may need to build Xen from source"

Answer (score 1):

I found another answer to this on [the XEN-WiKi](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Remus) which describes the process.

To me it looks not real stable and good for production use in its current state.

- patched old/buggy drbd 8.3.11
- 2.6.18 Kernel
- Remus did not change since 2011

There were some hints in the above link that some parts of it will be within the standard Linux 3.4 mainstream-kernel, and even the [project's home](http://nss.cs.ubc.ca/remus/) page says that it is still "young".

But this looks really interesting.

In the meantime I do my session-replication stuff with application-means. So my hot-standbys can take over without having to replicate a full machines state (including all disk and RAM memory).

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late reply but check out this wiki on Remus installation
http://remusha.wikidot.com

Comment: technically a little too late, but still a really useful link for when I try again on another set of boxes.

I'll mark this as the answer if/when I manage to get remus up and running